# Remote Desktop account always on

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, user-accounts, remote-access

Assumptions: 
1. I have set up a Remote Desktop Server
2. I have set up an account on the RDS namely RA01
3. LAN based network

Scenario: 
1. I logged in on my remote account namely RA01 on computer Comp01, open a paint app and maximized the window and left my Comp01.
2. 5mins after, I logged in on RA01 again on coomputer Comp02, seeing the same opened and maximized window of the paint application.

Question: how to achieve this?

Comment: The situation will work exactly as you described it. If you remote in from one computer and open an app and then go to a different computer and remote in again, as long as you're remoting into the same account on that remote computer, your app will still be open just as you left it. Unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @n8te so you mean to say up until I explicitly log off the remote account it will have the same programs opened?

Comment: Correct. I do this all the time at work. From computer 1 I remote into computer 2, do some work, and then go to a different building and remote into computer 2 from a new computer. Computer 2 is exactly as I left it. Unless you explicitly log off computer 2, it will stay just as it was. Even if I were to shutdown computer 1, it only disconnects me from computer 2; it does not log me off computer 2.

Comment: @n8te What if I turn off the RDP connection on Comp01 (without logging off the RA01 and while paint program is still on) and go to Comp02 to establish an RDP connection and logging in to RA01, would I still have the same outcome as before like the Paint program is still on or is the account RA01 reset itself?

Comment: You stayed logged in. All you're doing is diconnecting the remote session. It doesn't change the fact that you're logged into the remote PC. Until you explicitly log off/shutdown the remote PC, you will stay logged in. I have two PCs with me here right now. I will test this last scenario you asked about. One min.

Comment: Thank you so much for testing it, I will patiently wait for your reply

Comment: Verified just now. Remoted from PC 1 to PC2. Opened Paint. Disabled RDP service. Connection was broken. Logged into PC 2 locallly. Paint app was still open.